# How to know the penultimate item in the database laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

To get the last item I'm doing:

```
$balance = Balance::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest('created_at')->first();
```

I need to get the penultimate to be able to make a comparison of the result of the last balance and the penultimo .. I am trying to get the percentage difference from one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your laravel statment and just add the function skip(), which as his name implies skips n numbers of rows
 `$balance = Balance::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest('created_at')->skip(1)->first();`

From the official documentation [Skip](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-skip)